# can I change the galvanized nipple going into drain to PVC or other type of plastic?

Tags: plumbing

Can you switch put a galvanized drain nipple with plastic?
And of so would you use tape instead of pipe dope?
The guy at Lowes said pipe dope but many have said tape. Confused

Comment: I have no rationale for this. but a good quality tape just seems right with the PVC pipe.

Comment: I'm no plumber but just remodeled my kitchen. I swapped the galvanized setup starting at the wye. Went with ABS male adapter and typical plastic trap; used tape on the adapter. Passed inspection in California.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe dope is guaranteed to fill the gaps in the threads, but like @Hightower said, good quality tape seems right. Remember drains aren't under pressure, so either way is ok if you do a good job.

Comment: Agreed, either is fine. I prefer the no-fail-install of dope; tape has to be done right.

Comment: You have to use a pipe dope which is specifically compatible with PVC. Some of them (like for brass or iron pipe) apparently can react or damage the PVC.